# Using ASP.NET Web application as SignalR client

Tags: asp.net, azure, windows-services, signalr

My team is in the middle of deciding the architecture of our backend system:

> 1. Webserver A is an ASP.NET MVC application with ASP.NET Web API component, hosted in Azure Website.
> 2. Windows Service B is a self-hosted OWIN server that will periodically push notifications to clients who subscribes to the notification, hosted in Azure VM.
> 3. Windows Service C is a client that subscribes to notification from B, hosted in Azure VM.

Since we are more-or-less entrenched in `.NET` stack, we implemented B as `SignalR` server with C being the `SignalR` client. This part seems to work well.

Now comes a point where we also want A to subscribe to B, but I realize that it means an ASP.NET Web Server is going to act as `SignalR` CLIENT, instead of the typical scenario where it acts as `SignalR` server.

I presume we can initialize the `SignalR` connection in `Global.asax` and make the process ever-running to avoid `AppDomain` recycle. However, I feel a bit iffy when a Web Server is made to do something other than serving web requests. This solution also make the web server not stateless since it needs to maintain the web socket connection alive.

Is there something fundamentally wrong with making an `ASP.NET` application a `SignalR` client? Is there any possible gotcha with this setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Azure you cannot tell that your AppDomain will not recycle. Because of many reasons, it can restart itself to heal and then you will end up making a new connection to the SingleR server. Is that OK for you?

Also SingleR is mostly used in the Web Functionality improvement where polling and refresh on web clients is made simple. But as your requirement seems to be all a back end stuff, I would suggest you to go with any other event driven pattern. Check Azure Service Bus topic/subscription model to have different components listen to various events and act accordingly.